# Get the middle month from months represented in an array using only index, current month, and total number of items in array

Tags: javascript, recharts

I am implementing custom X axis ticks with `recharts` in a React app. Each X axis tick represents a month. I want to render the name of each month at each tick, and the year at the half way point between the first and last ticks that represent that year.

Here are the following scenarios:

1. If there are the chart is showing data from April 2022 to December 2022, I want the tick for "2022" to show up under August.
2. If I am showing the full year, I want the year tick to show up halfway between June and July.
3. If I am showing January to March, I want the year tick to show up under February.

I have access to the following data:

```
{
  index: number; // current index of tick being rendered
  visibleTicksCount: number; // total number of items in the data
  value: string; // a date string in the following format: "2023-07-01" for that tick
}
```

If we have data for April 2022 to March 2023, our data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    index: 0,
    value: '2022-04-01',
    visibleTicksCount: 12
  },
  ...
  {
    index: 11,
    value: '2023-03-01',
    visibleTicksCount: 12
  }
]
```

Knowing that there 12 months in a year, I want to know which month falls in the middle of that data for that year. If there are an odd number of months being represent, the month will be a whole number. Scenario one has 9 months, and the middle month is August, or `8`. Scenario 2 has 12 months, so the middle should be between June and July, or `6.5`.

I don't have access to the full array. Just the values shown above, `index`, `value`, and `visibleTicksCount`.

I am solving for X, I guess. I just don't know how best to approach this in a way that works.

I have tried the following:

```
function isMiddle(index, value, visibleTicksCount) {
  const [,month] = value.split('-').map(Number);

  return index + month + 12 - visibleTicksCount === 12;
}

isMiddle(0, '2022-04-01', 12) // false
isMiddle(1, '2022-05-01', 12) // false
isMiddle(4, '2022-08-01', 12) // true
isMiddle(2, '2022-06-01', 12) // false
...
```

This works when there an odd number of months for the years being represented. However, when the number of datums for a year are an even number, `isMiddle` does not return true. I need some kind of "offset" based upon what the index is and the number of `visibleTicksCount`.